# 7 day window with skipped dates

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have data with 300 stadiums and within a stadium I have number of visitors on each date that there was a game.  There is not a game each day.

For each stadium, I want to generate a series that gives a rolling 7 day sum of visitors.  I want the span of that series to be as small as possible so that the series starts 7 days before the first game and ends on the date of the last game.

This is what the data looks like for one particular stadium:

```
Game_date
2013-05-20    122
2013-06-27    350
2013-10-08    105
2013-10-10    100
2013-12-22    165
2013-12-24     55
2014-01-05    321
2014-01-06     71
2014-01-07    199
```

Sample of what I want the output to look like:

```
Date
...
2014-01-03    0
2014-01-04    0
2014-01-05    321
2014-01-06    392
2014-01-07    591
```

Comment: you asked a very good question complete with an example of your input and expected outputs. That helps make it much easier to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [rolling_sum](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.stats.moments.rolling_sum.html) function. It's a one liner for your example:

```
In [48]: pd.rolling_sum(df, window=7, freq='D', min_periods=1)
Out[48]:
            Game_date
2013-05-20        122
2013-05-21        122
2013-05-22        122
...
2014-01-04        NaN
2014-01-05        321
2014-01-06        392
2014-01-07        591
```

You can add `.fillna(0)` if you don't like the `NaN`s.

Comment: Nice!  I knew there was a function just for this type of thing.  Thank you

Comment: The use of `min_periods=1` there was insightful! I just learned something. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the data needs to be resampled before applying the rolling sum. I'm assuming that the starting dataframe is indexed by a pandas date.

```
df  = df.resample('D').fillna(0)
print df.tail()


            seats
game_date        
2014-01-03      0
2014-01-04      0
2014-01-05    321
2014-01-06     71
2014-01-07    199
```

so that fills in all the missing dates with zeros. Now we can apply the rolling sum.

```
print pd.rolling_sum( df, 7 ).tail()

            seats
game_date        
2014-01-03      0
2014-01-04      0
2014-01-05    321
2014-01-06    392
2014-01-07    591
```